# Why does expanding my functional dependency eliminate non-type variable arguments?

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies

I've been doing some work building my own custom prelude and I wanted to build a `Callable` type class that would implement function application (`($)`) for types other than functions.  So I built a type class using multi-parameter type classes:

```hs
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Prelude ()

class Callable a b c where
  ($) :: a -> b -> c
```

Now I went ahead and made functions an instance of the `Callable` type class which required me to enable flexible instances.

```hs
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

import Prelude ()

id :: a -> a
id x = x

class Callable a b c where
  ($) :: a -> b -> c

instance Callable (a -> b) a b where
  ($) = id
```

This is nice and now I can use `($)` on functions.  So the next logical step for me was to implement function composition (`(.)`) as well.  After a bit of fiddling I realized that in order to do so I was going to need to make `Callable` functionally dependent so I turned on functional dependencies.

```hs
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Prelude ()

id :: a -> a
id x = x

class Callable a b c | a b -> c where
  ($) :: a -> b -> c

instance Callable (a -> b) a b where
  ($) = id

(.) :: (Callable f1 intype intermediate, Callable f2 intermediate outtype) => f2 -> f1 -> intype -> outtype
(.) a b c = a $ (b $ c)
```

This does in fact compile fine. In fact if I can use my `(.)` to make functions.  However if I attempt to use my new functions (at least in any way I have attempted) it fails to typecheck with a rather cryptic error.

```hs
 ~/p/dynamo > ghci callable.hs
GHCi, version 8.4.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( callable.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :t (id).(id)
(id).(id)
  :: (Callable (a1 -> a1) c e, Callable (a2 -> a2) e d) => c -> d
*Main> ((id).(id)) $ ()

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Callable (c1 -> d) () c2
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall c1 d c2 a1 e a2.
              (Callable (c1 -> d) () c2, Callable (a1 -> a1) c1 e,
               Callable (a2 -> a2) e d) =>
              c2
*Main>
```

I am not really able to understand what this error is trying to convey.  But it suggests I turn on flexible contexts so I thought I'd give it a whirl, if it fixes the issue that's great, and if it changes the error I might get at the problem.  However if I turn on flexible contexts, the error does not change, in fact it even still suggests that I turn on flexible contexts.

At this point I thought I would do some reading. I read around a few questions about `Non type-variable argument`, but I didn't really feel like I was gaining any insight into my particular problem.  It is at this point that something in the back of my mind made me think to make `b` a functional dependency as well.  I have no idea why, but this does, in fact, fix my problem.  Here is what the working code looks like:

```hs
{-# Language MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FunctionalDependencies #-}

import Prelude ()

id :: a -> a
id x = x

class Callable a b c | a -> b c where
  ($) :: a -> b -> c

instance Callable (a -> b) a b where
  ($) = id

(.) :: (Callable f1 intype intermediate, Callable f2 intermediate outtype) => f2 -> f1 -> intype -> outtype
(.) a b c = a $ (b $ c)
```

So my question of course is why the heck does this work?  What was I doing wrong and how did the change fix it?

Comment: You know, this actually compiles and runs just fine for me. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin As it says, I am using 8.4.2.

Comment: If it suggests turning on flexible contexts, you haven't turned those on. You could add the extension to those at the beginning of the file, for instance.

Answer (score 6):

With the fundep `a b -> c`, you’re saying that the function type (`a`) and the argument type (`b`) determine the result type (`c`). Changing this to `a -> b c` means that the function type determines both the argument and result types, which is what you want: if `a` is replaced with `a' -> b'`, `b` with `a'`, and `c` with `b'`, then indeed the function type is what contains the information you need to remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn on `FlexibleContexts` in ghci.  ghci does not enable extensions interactively just because they were used in a file you have loaded.  It's a bit awkward sometimes, but I understand why.  You can load multiple files at once, which can each specify different extensions - and you probably don't want the union of all the extensions, as some extensions don't play well with others.

You can either invoke ghci with `-XFlexibleContexts` at the command line, or use `:set -XFlexibleContexts` within ghci to enable it.

As for why you're being asked to enable it in the first place?  Haskell has very restrictive rules on the forms of contexts.  The restrictive rules came from historical fears that it might add significant implementation complexity to relax them.  It turns out there's no harm in relaxing them, which is what that extension does.  It's reached the point that I don't even remember what it was supposed to protect against - if the compiler asks, I turn that extension on.